# Issue with background cover and contain, image is not displaying correctly

Tags: css

i have this image looks crisp and clear

[image]

but when i try to load same in website it looks covered from side and looks bad
here is live site
https://itsneotpras.myshopify.com/

i have this code

```
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
border-radius: 50px;
bottom: 20px;
right: 2%;
background-image: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0033/3538/9233/files/1905.png);
background-size: auto;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
--pushdaddy-background: transparent;
--pushdaddy-box-shadow: none;
background-size: contain;
box-shadow: none;
```

here is html

```
<div id="pushdaddy-button" class="pushdaddy-button pwapp-animated pwapp-onlythree " style="width:60px;height:60px;border-radius: 50px;bottom: 20px;right:2%; ; background-image:url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0033/3538/9233/files/1905.png);background-size: auto;background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat; --pushdaddy-background: transparent;--pushdaddy-box-shadow: none;background-size: contain; ; ;box-shadow: none;"></div>
```

i tried different settings and it does not work. it works in one condition when i increase the width and height to 70px  and set  background-size: auto;
then it works but why i should make 70px when image is 50px in original and in 60px it should have been clear and crispy

it should look like this

```
  https://prnt.sc/1sb2pxk
```

Comment: Can you please include your HTML, or enough code to reproduce your issue

Comment: included................

Comment: I see it correctly, at least on the web page you provided, what is the expected output?

Comment: The logo looks correct. I think you may not have noticed the white border around the logo before?

Comment: @AnikethMalyala it should look like this https://prnt.sc/1sb2pxk

Comment: @Castle  it should look like this prnt.sc/1sb2pxk –

Comment: @BeerusDev  it should look like this prnt.sc/1sb2pxk –

Comment: 1.   The image you want to "look like"  is different from the one you are using

2.  The image you are using have 50x50px but you are oversizing it in your css, that could be the reason why it looks "pixeled"

Comment: It doesn't need to change size right? Why not just set its dimensions explicitly? E.g. `background-size: 50px` If you need the image to be `60px` then rather use an image at that size at a higher resolution with more pixel density.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
```

to

```
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
```

Because the image you are using have 50x50px and you are oversizing it

Comment: Have you tried: background-size 50px?

Comment: yes i tried and implemented that.